# Системная переменная, указывающая путь до файла

Tags: java, вконтакте, gradle

Начал изучать работу с VK API на Java. Для облегчения работы решил использовать Java SDK от Вконтакте. На этапе установки столкнулся со следующей задачей:

> Установить системную переменную, указывающую путь до файла:
>
> -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties

Не имею ни малейшего представления где это прописать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ваш ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/865554/177188) частично правильный, данный вариант установит значение переменной внутри кода.

Чтобы задать значение этой переменной на этапе запуска приложения, например если вы хотите использовать разные параметры логирования для разных сред (разработка, тестирование, продакшн), то используйте опции java:

Например

```
java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties yourClass
```

или для jar файла

```
java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -jar file.jar
```

Опции начинающиеся с `-D` как раз и устанавливают системные переменные для java приложения, подробнее в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, но нашёл следующий вариант:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", "logging.properties");
```

Методом проб и ошибок узнаю правильный ли это вариант.